# Different column names for different databases with Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, identifier, maxlength

A database was recently migrated to Oracle and some column names had to be shortened because of the maximum identifier length of 30.

This application already runs in production in a few environments so shortening the column names everywhere would be considered only as a last resort.

I thought about implementing a PhysicalNamingStrategy and LogicalNamingStrategy but it wouldn't work because I wouldn't be able to resolve the logical name from a shortened physical name.

I suspect that I could create a base entity for those situations and extend it to only overwrite the column name.  But that would force me to explicitly list the entity classes to be used in the persistence.xml.

Anyone has a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I extended the PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl and overwrote the **toPhysicalColumnName** method because the only issue we had was with some column names that were too long for Oracle.  This code will truncate the string to 30 characters if the identifier is any longer and if the database is Oracle.

```
package my.package;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class CustomNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        if (jdbcEnv.getDialect().toString().indexOf("Oracle") > -1 && identifier.getText().length() > 30) {
            return Identifier.toIdentifier(identifier.getText().substring(0, 30));
        } else {
            return identifier;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that each of my entity fields are already annotated with the @Column annotation in which the physical name is specified. You can see bellow a column name that had to be truncated for Oracle:

```
@Column(name = "MARKER_DISTANCE_START_POINT_CHAR")
public String getMarkerDistanceStartPointChar() {
    return this.markerDistanceStartPointChar;
}

public void setMarkerDistanceStartPointChar(String markerDistanceStartPointChar) {
    this.markerDistanceStartPointChar = markerDistanceStartPointChar;
}
```

I then needed to adjust my hibernate configuration to register my custom naming strategy.  Do do so with JPA, you add the following **hibernate.physical_naming_strategy** property in your **persistence.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pu_name">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jndyName</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="my.package.CustomNamingStrategy"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This it isn't sexy, but it solves it. Hoping this solution can help others.